# TcpServer Cant Accept More Connections After Some Days

Tags: delphi, indy, connection, tcpserver

I'm looking for help, what happens is that after a few days my tcpserver to accept connections. more or less always in 1400 connections.
I use a class (TObject) to register the connections and destroy when the client disconnects but apparently always gets stuck connections.

```
Type 
TSimpleClient = class(TObject)
IP          : ShortString;
Connection  : TidTCPServerConnection;
Deteccao    : ShortString;
Existe      : ShortString;
Contagem    : Integer;
Bloqueado   : ShortString;
Serial      : ShortString;
Thread      : Pointer;
end;
```

no onconnect faço o seguinte:

```
Client              := TSimpleClient.Create;
Client.IP           := AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
Client.Thread       := AThread;
Client.Serial       := Received;
Client.Connection   := AThread.Connection;
AThread.Data := Client;
```

e no ondisconnect:

```
  Client  := Pointer(AThread.Data);
IP      := Client.IP;
Serial  := Client.Serial;
try
Client.Free;
finally
AThread.Data := nil;
end;
```

I've used record to store and release the connections but always have this problem with stuck connections and at a time the server to receive connections.

---

**Update**: my onxecute its simply. something like this:

```
Client := Pointer(AThread.Data);
try
  Received := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;
  Received := Protege('D', Received);
  A := TStringList.Create;
  Split('=', Received, A);
  if A[0] = 'teste' then begin
    //...
  end;
  A.Free;
except
  on e: Exception do begin
    AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Indy uses 1 thread per connected client.  In a single 32-bit process, Windows will start failing to create new threads when it hits the max 2GB memory limit (see [Does Windows have a limit of 2000 threads per process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773)) at approx 1400-2000 simultaneous threads, depending on the default stack size used per thread.

If you need to handle more clients, you will have to either:

1. tweak your project's settings to lower the default thread stack size for your executable.  The default value is 1MB.
2. write a custom `TIdPeerThread`-derived class that bypasses the `TThread` constructor and calls the RTL's `BeginThread()` function directly with a custom stack size.  And then assign a `TIdThreadMgrDefault` or `TIdThreadMgrPool` component to your server's `ThreadMgr` property, and then assign your class type to the thread manager's `ThreadClass` property.
3. use some kind of load balancing system to handle clients amongst multiple server processes.

Ether way, when dealing with that many clients, you should consider deriving a custom class from `TIdPeerThread` per #2 above so you can put your custom fields in that class.  This way, you do not have to use the `TIdPeerThread.Data` property to track additional objects in memory, which will save some space.  For example:

```
type 
  TSimpleClient = class(TIdPeerThread)
  public
    IP          : ShortString;
    Deteccao    : ShortString;
    Existe      : ShortString;
    Contagem    : Integer;
    Bloqueado   : ShortString;
    Serial      : ShortString;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdThreadMgrDefault1.ThreadClass := TSimpleClient;
end;

procedure TMyForm.IdTCPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  Client: TSimpleClient;
  Received: string;
begin
  Client              := TSimpleClient(AThread);
  Client.IP           := AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;

  Received := ...;
  Client.Serial       := Received;

  //...
end;

procedure TMyForm.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  Client: TSimpleClient;
  IP, Serial: string;
begin
  Client  := TSimpleClient(AThread);
  IP      := Client.IP;
  Serial  := Client.Serial;
  //...

  // no need to free the Client here...
end;

procedure TMyForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  Client: TSimpleClient;
  Received: string;
begin
  Client  := TSimpleClient(AThread);

  Received := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;
  Received := Protege('D', Received);
  A := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Split('=', Received, A);
    if (A.Count > 0) and (A[0] = 'teste') then
    begin
      //...
    end;
  finally
    A.Free;
  end;

  // no need to catch an exception here just to
  // Disconnect, TIdTCPServer handles that for you...
end;
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the accounts get caught and end up causing this problem. but why get stuck I do not know.

I use this code to see how many have connected:

function Online: Integer;
var
  NumClients: Integer;
begin
  with Form1.IdTCPServer1.Threads.LockList do
  try
    NumClients := Count;
  finally
    Form1.IdTCPServer1.Threads.UnlockList;
  end;

  Result := NumClients;
end;

Comment: You have not shown any of your `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` code yet, so there is no way to diagnose that problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you're properly cleaning up objects when connections close, you should look into [`setsockopt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx) and `SO_REUSEADDR`. When a connection closes, the TCP subsystem will, by default, keep the combination of address and port occupied in a wait-state, just to catch any data that may be left 'on the line' right after the disconnect. (If I remember correctly for up to 10 minutes.) You can check this with the [`netstat -a`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137984) command line utility.

If your service handles a lot of connections, it may indeed stop responding after a couple of thousand connections because all outgoing TCP ports are occupied in this way.

To avoid this set `SO_REUSEADDR` to true with `setsockopt`, on each connection once, so the system allows re-use of the address and port combination. Like so:

```
var
  i:integer;
begin
  i:=1;
  setsockopt(Socket.Handle,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,@i,4);
```

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, my onxecute its simply. something like this:
'Client := Pointer(AThread.Data);
    
  try
    Received  := AThread.Connection.ReadLn;
    Received  := Protege('D', Received);
    
    A         := TStringList.Create;
    
    Split('=', Received, A);

    if A[0] = 'teste' then begin}
end;
A.Free;
    
  except
    on e: Exception do begin
      AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;

on connect and onexecute i access another my procedure who create a TSqlConnection and TSqlDataSet at runtime to insert and check infos, use then and free. is it the error? i think not.

Comment: @DouglasRuiz, please edit your question and put the code there, not in a comment...

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, with your code i cant connect more than once, and if i'm disconnected i have error on onexecute (invalid pointer).

Comment: @DouglasRuiz: Then you are doing something wrong. Please edit your question to show your latest code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau with your code i can only connect one time, if i disconnect and try connect again the server dont do nothing :/

Comment: @DouglasRuiz: You still have not done what I asked you to do 3 weeks ago - "*Please edit your question to **show your latest code**.*".  And please show *all* of your relevant code.  What does the value of `Received` look like when `ReadLn()` exits? Is it even exiting at all? What does `Protege()` look like? What does `Split()` look like? Are you sure `A` is not empty when `Split()` exits? You said you are performing SQL queries, what does that code look like? There is an error in your code, but we can't see everything you are actually doing. And have you tried my `ThreadClass` suggestion yet?